# Regular Expression Following Match

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I have this regular expression which currently matches the last space and its following word in a string:

```
var regex = /\s+\S*$/m
```

For example:

```
'this match'.match(regex) == [" match"]
```

However, if the whole string is just a whitespace character and then word characters it will still match. (such as `' match'`)

I've experimented with the ["not followed by" quantifier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_nfollow.asp), but the closest I've come has been to match the inverse of my preferred output:

```
var regex = /\S+(?=\s+\S*$)/m
'this match'.match(regex) == ["this"]
```

**I would like this to only match a space, then a word if that match is followed by any number of word characters**

So I'd like it to match the last space and word of this: `'multiple words'`

But not match this at all: `' word'`

**EDIT:** I should add that I intend to use the search() method (or something comparable) to get the index of the character at the beginning of the match. I only used the match() method above for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
/.(\s\w+)/
```

This will match any character followed by a whitespace character, followed by one or more word characters, captured in group 1. You then just have to extract that group. For example:

```
'multiple words'.match(/.(\s\w+)/)[1] // " words"
' word'.match(/.(\s\w+)/)             // null
```

Note that I used `.` in this pattern because the question is a bit vague about what you wanted to *not* match, citing only "*just a whitespace character and then word characters*". If you'd like to ensure that there are some word characters preceding the captured group, use something like this:

```
/\w\s*(\s\w+)/
```

To get the index of the first match using the first pattern is pretty easy. Just use [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) and add 1:

```
'multiple words'.search(/.(\s\w+)/) + 1 // 8
' word'.match(/.(\s\w+)/) + 1           // 0 (not found)
```

But if you're using second pattern, it's a lot more difficult. JavaScript does not provide an easy way to get the position of each capture group. The best you could do is to use [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) which will give you the capture groups *and* the index where the match was found, then do something like this:

```
match = /\w\s*(\s\w+)/.exec('multiple words');
index = match.index + match[0].length - match[1].length; // 8

match = /\w\s*(\s\w+)/.exec(' words');                   // undefined
```

Comment: I'd use `\S` instead of `.` so it doesn't match something like `  word` with two leading spaces.

Comment: I added an edit to my original post. What you've given me can (thankfully) get me there, but it would require the extra step of subtracting the match[1] value's length from the original string's length to get an index. Is there a way to make this output the desired match's index when used with the string.search() method?